# Excel: auto format time of day when inputting time

Tags: excel, time, format, vba

I'm inputting time in and time out logs for my business to calculate the total hours worked by individual contractor companies visiting my site.  We operate from 6:30am to 5pm.  Excel automatically formats the data as AM, except for 12:00-12:59 which it correctly assumes is PM.  I need excel to recognize that any time between 12:00 and 5:00 is PM.  This will save me from having to type PM for each "time out" which over the course of a year will save me hours.

I'm not really sure how to do this.  I'm guessing an if/then macro?

Answer (score 0):

I just use military time to get around this problem.   5 PM is not 5:00, but rather 17:00.  Then you don't need to put in a PM or anything.  Note: This is just for inputting the time.  You can still display the time as 5:00 PM or whatever by formatting those cells or columns as the 'Time' type.

```
1 PM = 13:00
2 PM = 14:00
3 PM = 15:00
4 PM = 16:00
5 PM = 17:00
6 PM = 18:00
```

etc.

Comment: @Jon Zotz This is only for inputting the time, you can still have the time display as 5:00 PM by formatting those cells or columns as the 'Time' type.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cell format as shown below:
[image: cell format]

when you type 17:00 is correctly displayed as 5:00 PM